# Can I set cookies for discord.Embed.set_thumbnail in discord.py?

Tags: discord.py, embed

I am making an online encyclopedia searching bot with discord.py. But the encyclopedia site is opened only for my school students. So I had to use cookies to get documents' contents. But I got a problem. The site provides changing the logo for each document, and I'm going to put it in `discord.Embed.thumbnail`. As I mentioned above, the encyclopedia site is opened only for my school students, and the logo file as well as.
Can I use my cookies to access file link for `discord.Embed.set_thumbnail`? If possible, how? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you could currently use the [requests](https://www.w3schools.com/python/module_requests.asp) module to get the image URL setting cookies. Then, you get the URL of the image and you just put it into the thumbnail field.

Comment: Most of the site directories are hidden to people, and even the URLs of images are. I had already tried it and failed.